# Difference between replace and put for HashMap

Tags: java, replace, hashmap

I want to make a histogram by using a `HashMap`, the key should be the delay, the value the amount of times this delay occurs. I am doubting to use the `HashMap` `replace` or the `HashMap` `put` function if an already existing delay has an new occurence. I did it by this way:

```
int delay = (int) (loopcount-packetServed.getArrivalTime());
if(histogramType1.containsKey(delay)) {
    histogramType1.replace(delay, histogramType1.get(delay) + 1);   
} else {
    histogramType1.put(delay, 1);
}
```

Is this correct? or should I use two times the put function?

Comment: [Replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#replace-K-V-) "Replaces the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to some value"

Comment: So I should keep the replace solution ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter in that case since if the element exists it should have the same result as `put` anyways - since `containsKey` is used `replace` is only called if there is a mapping.

Comment: I want the key to stay the same, but the value attached to that key should be incremented by 1, I think using the put function would cause to have 2 times the key with a different value attached to it.

Comment: No, maps don't allow duplicate keys so calling `put` instead of `replace` also results in the old value being removed.

Answer (score 69):

There is absolutely no difference in `put` and `replace` when there is a current mapping for the wanted key. From [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#replace-K-V-):

> Replaces the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to some value.

This means that if there is already a mapping for the given key, both `put` and `replace` will update the map in the same way. Both will also return the previous value associated with the key. However, if there is no mapping for that key, then `replace` will be a no-op (will do nothing) whereas `put` will still update the map.

---

Starting with Java 8, note that you can just use

```
histogramType1.merge(delay, 1, Integer::sum);
```

This will take care of every condition. From [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with `null`, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is `null`.

In this case, we are creating the entry `delay -> 1` if the entry didn't exist. If it did exist, it is updated by incrementing the value by 1.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, since you first check if the value is contained in the map, using `put` or `replace` leads to the same result.

You can use either, based on what is more readable to you.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the sources you can see the following (this is from update 11 but probably hasn't changed much):

**replace**:

```
if ((e = getNode(hash(key), key)) != null) {
    V oldValue = e.value;
    e.value = value;
    afterNodeAccess(e);
    return oldValue;
}
```

**put** (internal method putVal):

```
//some code before this to find the node e (similar to getNode(hash(key)))
if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
   V oldValue = e.value;
   if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)  //onlyIfAbsent is false here
     e.value = value;
   afterNodeAccess(e);
   return oldValue;
}
```

As you can see, the relevant parts of the code do basically the same thing since `onlyIfAbsent` is false for `put` and thus always will replace the value.

Answer (score 3):

You can verify the behavior the others have described, with this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.replace("a", "1");
        System.out.println(map.get("a"));

        map.put("a", "1");
        System.out.println(map.get("a"));

        map.replace("a", "2");
        System.out.println(map.get("a"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace won't add the object unless the key is already mapped, put will replace existing value and if it is new, will create a new entry.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#replace-K-V-

**public V replace(K key,V value)**
Replaces the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to some value.

**public V put(K key,V value)**
Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.