# Cannot use HashMap replace method : call require api level 24 (current min is 22):java.util.HashMap#replace

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hashmap

So guys, why can't I use the HashMap replace method on my Android Studio project?

```
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> scoreLine = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
scoreLine.put(0, 22;
scoreLine.put(1, 46);
scoreLine.put(2, 89);

scoreLine.replace(1, 49); // I can't use this
scoreLine.replace(1, 46, 49); // I can't use this either
```

Even though I can use the put method to add item

Here is though my gradle.build (just some part of the code)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.practiceprojectweekend"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I did indeed set the current minSdkVersion is 22
and that replace method require minmum level 24

I do replace that minSDK to 24
But then I couldn't not run the app using my Android Device

Is there a way to get around this without changing the minSdkVersion ?

Comment: why are you replacing and not using put again?


https://stackoverflow.com/a/35297640/4682816
another question which may provide insight

Comment: Does it just gonna override the item with the same key ?
Wow, I didn't know that

Comment: So, yes, I just check it. And the "put" indeed can be used to "replace"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between replace and put for HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297537/difference-between-replace-and-put-for-hashmap)

Comment: In fairness, the duplicate is arguable...it covers the similarity between `put` and `replace`, but it doesn't cover the Android SDK aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to get around this without changing the minSdkVersion.  `replace(K, V)` was added in SDK version 24, and `replace(K, V, V)` was added in SDK version 26.

As noted in the comments, `put` will replace an existing value.

You can see more details in the [docs page](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Well I see now, it said it self that :  
"Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is **replaced**."

Comment: @phaphapha Glad I could help.  I've gotten this type of error message on my android projects too many times to count (I use cordova, which by default specifies Java 1.6, but I also use a library that needs Java 1.7, so I have to go fix the setting in the config files on a regular basis.  Ugh!)

Comment: You say replace was added in SDK 24, but it is a part of the standard Java collections library so why would that be?

Comment: Andrew, I'm not sure I follow your question. Are you asking why Google didn't implement it until SDK 24? Or why I say that it was added in SDK 24? Or something else?