# Difference between map.replace() and map.put() for updating a value in Map in Collection Framework

Tags: java, oop, methods, collections, hashmap

I was given a question on codeforces  and I was able to understand the solution and even did the solution but I was stuck to a place where

**map.replace(i,map.get(i)+1)** was able to update my values present at an index whereas

**map.put(index , map.get(index)+1)** was not giving me the required result
I've seen suuggestions on Stackoverflow where for updating the values it is suggested that map.put() can also be used.

So my question is -

1.What's the **difference between these two approaches** if there exists some difference?

2.Why is it that when I use **map.put(index , map.get(index)++)** for updating the value at a given index I get an error that at map.get(index)++

variable is required not a value i.e

required: variable
found:    value

while there is **no such error while** when I am **using map.get(index)+1** there is no such error. Why is it so ?

**Question Link** - https://codeforces.com/contest/621/problem/B

**Solution link** -    `https://ideone.com/wgDAFM`

```
* package whatever; // don't place package name! */
 
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
 
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
 
        Map<Integer,Integer> add_diag = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,Integer> sub_diag = new HashMap<>();
 
        for(int i=0;i<=2005;i++){
            add_diag.put(i,0);
            sub_diag.put(i,0);
        }
 
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            String s = br.readLine();
            String s1[] = s.split(" ");
 
            int x = Integer.parseInt(s1[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(s1[1]);
 
            if(x-y<0){
 
                sub_diag.replace(999-(x-y),sub_diag.get(999-(x-y))+1);
            }
            else{
                int temp = sub_diag.get(x-y);
                sub_diag.replace(x-y,sub_diag.get(x-y)+1);
            }
 
            add_diag.replace(x+y,add_diag.get(x+y)+1);
        }
 
        int res = 0;
 
        for(int value : sub_diag.values() ){
            res+=(value*(value-1))/2;
        }
 
        for(int value : add_diag.values() ){
            res+=(value*(value-1))/2;
        }
 
        System.out.println(res);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return;
    }
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Have you read the JavaDoc of [`Map.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)) and [`Map.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#replace(K,V))? If you did, do you **still** need help understanding the difference?

Comment: Thank u for the link it helped me out to clear some of my doubts but still not very clear as it it is mentioned that in map.put() function old value is "replaced" by new value and same thing is written for map.replace() function that it "replaces the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to some value" . which means almost the same thing to me. Correct me if I am wrong.  Also could u please help me resolve my 2nd doubt too?

Comment: Yes, they do almost the same thing with the exception that `replace` only changes the map if the key has already been mapped to a value before (in other words it never increases the size of the map).

Comment: Thank u @JoachimSauer for giving your time onto this.

Comment: Can u please help me in understanding this concept @HenryTwist  a little more ?

Comment: What do you need help understanding? I think the documentation (and @JoachimSauer) perfectly explains it. The `replace` documentation even gives a default implementation which uses `put` directly.

Comment: In fact, there is a duplicate question for this, so it should probably be closed: [Difference between replace and put for HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297537/difference-between-replace-and-put-for-hashmap)

Comment: Can u please clear the 2nd doubt in the question for me i.e. as to why there is an error in using map.put(index , map.get(index)++) ?. It would be very helpful. @HenryTwist

Comment: `x++` is the same as writing `x = x + 1`. So `map.get(index)++` is the same as writing `map.get(index) = map.get(index) + 1`, which makes no sense, you can't reassign a method call.

Comment: Now I have understood clearly why it was throwing an error. Thank u so much for clearing this doubt for me @HenryTwist!!